# C, pointers - functions to initialize nested structs with struct Arrays (edited for details and clarity)

Tags: c, pointers, struct, memory-management, initializer

Learning C and I'm extreeeemely confused about pointers and initializing structs.

I have struct PlayerType and struct TeamType, with an init function declared in a header file. This file looks like:

```
typedef struct {
    int number;
    int heaight;    //inches
    int weight;     //pounds
    char *name;
} PlayerType;

typedef struct {
    char *name;
    PlayerType players[12];
} TeamType;

PlayerType* initializePlayer(int, int, int, char*);
TeamType*   initializeTeam(char*, PlayerType*);
```

I would like to write functions in an init.c file to initialize various teams and players, however I don't know how it works with pointers and such. Let's say I have a function that I want to initialize a player, with dynamically allocated memory, that would return a player (EDITED with whoami's fixes, thanks!):

```
PlayerType* initializePlayer(int number, int height, int weight, char *name){
    PlayerType* plyr = (PlayerType*)malloc(sizeof(PlayerType)); // should be typecasted and wrong sizeof argument
    if(plyr != NULL){
        plyr->number = number;
        plyr->name = name;
        plyr->weight = weight;
        plyr->height = height;  
    }
    return plyr;
}
```

(EDIT: code worked fine, wasn't compiling the other files - like I said, very new to C)
This gives me a mess when compiling, (...)

In my main function, I've got some players initialized, but I can't figure out how to get the team initialized properly, and then add the players to it.

```
int main() {
    PlayerType plyr1 = initializePlayer(13, 75, 190, "Bob Smith");
    PlayerType plyr2 = initializePlayer(16, 80, 200, "Danny Clark");
    PlayerType plyr3 = initializePlayer(28, 91, 210, "Mike Green");
    PlayerType plyr4 = initializePlayer(20, 103, 225, "Alex Albert");       
    
    free(plyr1);
    free(plyr2);
    free(plyr3);
    free(plyr4);
    return 0;
}
```

Which is all well and good and works fine. What I cannot figure out is how to get my initializeTeam function going with the array of players. My instinct is:

```
TeamType* initializeTeam(char* name, PlayerType players[]) {
    TeamType* team = (TeamType*) malloc(sizeof(team));
    if(team != NULL) {
        team->name = name;
        team->players = players[12];
    }
    return team;
 }
```

Which I would think would take an array of size 12 of player structs and store it in the team struct's players attribute. That gives me `assignment to expression with array type`, when compiling, but I can't figure out anywhere in my code players isn't defined as an array, which is my thought.

I'd like to initialize a team struct using that function, and then do something like:

```
team->players[0] = plyr1;
team->players[1] = plyr2;
team->players[2] = plyr3;
....
```

Thanks in advance, and hopefully this time my question is posed correctly.

Comment: There is a semicolon missing after your second typedef.The compiler finds it in 10us. it took me 1s.

Comment: Your code is not that bad, but what you've presented of it does not appear to be sufficient to explain the conflicting types warning.  This sort of thing is why we generally expect debugging questions such as this to contain a [mre].  However, I can say that you appear to have an error in `initializePlayer()`.  Where you say `if(myProd != NULL)`, you probably mean `if(plyr != NULL)`.

Answer (score 0):

i saw a few error in your code

1. forget to include <stdlib.h>

   required to use malloc and free function
2. typos in struct definition
3. wrong declaration in initializePlayer function
4. initializePlayer function return a pointer not a struct
5. sizeof wrong type when allocate memory using malloc, sizeof(*plyr) is bug

here the fixed code

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h> // include stdlib for malloc function

    typedef struct {
        int number;
        int height;     // inches, typos height or heiaght
        int weight;     // pounds
        char *name;
    } PlayerType;

    typedef struct {
        char *name;
        PlayerType players[12];
    } TeamType;

    PlayerType* initializePlayer(int, int, int, char*); // fix char to char*

    int main() {
        PlayerType* plyr1 = initializePlayer(13, 75, 190, "Bob Smith");
        printf("Superstar %s, weighing %d pounds and standing %d inches tall, wearing number %d", plyr1->name, plyr1->weight, plyr1->height, plyr1->number);

        free(plyr1);
        return 0;
    }

    PlayerType* initializePlayer(int number, int height, int weight, char *name){
        PlayerType* plyr = (PlayerType*)malloc(sizeof(PlayerType)); // should be typecasted and wrong sizeof argument
        if(plyr != NULL){
            plyr->number = number;
            plyr->name = name;
            plyr->weight = weight;
            plyr->height = height;  
        }
        return plyr;
    }
```

You should learn more and try to understand pointer and struct to get better in C